# weblogic cluster eclipse target

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic

i'm currently maintaining a struts / spring java webapp running on weblogic 10.3.6 . I use eclipse neon for development, gradle 2.14 and git to do so.

Our customer wants to incorporate weblogic's clustering features so i'm trying to get my head around that.

I managed to set up a cluster with two servers and to deploy the application to it via weblogic administration console.

Now i'm trying to access the cluster in eclipse but it is not visible as a target. I tried restarting weblogic and re-adding the server.

In Oracle's tutorial there is no hint on what else i should configure on either side: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/javaservice/JCS/eclipse_jcs/eclipse_jcs.html#section2

Has any of you seen such behavior ? What else could i do ?

Thanks in advance for any hint !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, magically, all of a sudden all clusters appeared in eclipse server list... Probably after one or two restarts of weblogic...